# ValueError in finding Kaprekar numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

> In mathematics, a Kaprekar number for a given base is a non-negative integer,  the representation of whose square in that base can be split into two parts that add up to the original number again. For instance, 45 is a Kaprekar number, because 45² = 2025 and 20+25 = 45.
>   I want to print all Kaprekar numbers between two integers p and q

```
def kaprekarNumbers(p, q):
    for i in range(int(p),int(q)):
        square = str(i ** 2)
        if len(square) % 2 == 0:
            p1 , p2 = square[:len(square)/2] , square[len(square)/2:]
        else:
            p1 , p2 = square[:int(len(square)/2)] , square[int(len(square)/2) :]
        if int(p1) + int(p2) == int(i):
            print(i , end = '')
```

Error:
Compiler message :

```
Runtime Error
Error(stderr) : 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "solution.py", line 26, in <module>
    kaprekarNumbers(p, q)
  File "solution.py", line 17, in kaprekarNumbers
    if int(p1) + int(p2) == int(i):
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: This code doesn't even attempt to convert any strings to floats. Please post a [mcve] and the complete, exact stack trace.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Edited ! Added error into body .

Comment: please edit the error into the body of your question as text

Comment: What's the value of p and q for which you're getting this error?

Comment: @KartikMadaan: Your posted code doesn't run, as there's no call to the function.  The error in your comment doesn't produce the error isn't what you posted in your title.  Also, you've not even *tried* to trace the problem by even `print`ing the values you use.

Comment: What are the `p` and `q` values?

Comment: I don't know how to get the stack trace as I'm coding on Hackerrank and I'm fairly new to python ! And for the example , please refer to the exact problem page : [Link]https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/kaprekar-numbers/problem

Comment: @Prune , the values of p and q are passed by helper function . I just need to complete the given function .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `p` is an integer in the range [0,3], so that its square is a single-digit integer, then your split of the squares string version will produce an empty string for `p1`.  int('') is an error.  You have to check that value before you attempt to convert:

```
if len(square) >= 2:
    # Put your existing code here;
    # If square is only a single digit, there's no use splitting the result.
```

Better yet, cover the single-digit case, so you pick up `1` as a valid number:

```
    if p1 == '':
        p1 = '0'       # Force a leading zero.
    if int(p1) + int(p2) == int(i):
```

Comment: Even though I've rectified this error , I'm getting yet another error<br> 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "solution.py", line 26, in <module>
    kaprekarNumbers(p, q)
  File "solution.py", line 14, in kaprekarNumbers
    p1 , p2 = square[:len(square)/2] , square[len(square)/2:]
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method`<br>
 Can you please suggest some improvements in the code . Thanks :D

Comment: Shouldn't it be "*range [1:3]*"?

Comment: Actually, 0 is allowable according to the formal definition.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more advanced implementation (for when you will be more familiarized with *Python*).

*code.py*:

```
import sys


def kaprekar(n, base=10):
    #if i <= 0:
    #    return False
    square = n ** 2
    splitter = base
    while True:
        div, mod = divmod(square, splitter)
        if mod and div + mod == n:
            return True
        if splitter >= square:
            return False
        splitter *= base
    return False


def print_kaprekars(p, q, base=10):
    for i in range(p, q):
        if kaprekar(i, base=base):
            print(i)


def main():
    lo = 0
    hi = 1000
    base = 10
    print("Printing Kaprekar numbers (!!! base 10 representation !!!) between {:d} and {:d} in base {:d}".format(lo, hi, base))
    print_kaprekars(lo, hi, base=base)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    main()
```

**Notes**:

- `kaprekar` function:

  - Tests whether a number satisfies *Kaprekar* conditions
  - Supports bases other than 10 (default)
  - Does everything mathematically (no string conversions or parsing - this way you **wouldn't encounter current error**, and also waaay faster)

    - The "position" in the squared number "held" by `splitter` (going right -> left) and the 2 parts are computed using [[Python]: **divmod**(*a, b*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod)
- The rest are just wrappers

**Output**:

> ```
> (py35x64_test) e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q050846444>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py35x64_test\Scripts\python.exe" code.py
> Python 3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> Printing Kaprekar numbers (!!! base 10 representation !!!) between 0 and 1000 in base 10
> 1
> 9
> 45
> 55
> 99
> 297
> 703
> 999
> ```